# React Native Stripe initPaymentSheet returning "paymentOption": undefined

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I've followed the docs of stripe for mobile integration using react native I'm however stuck at initPaymentSheet

I didn't write the rest because initPaymentSheet is returning "paymentOption": undefined
on stripe dahsboard, a customer is being created an ephemeralKey is created as well and returned successfully

here's my code:
App.js

```
<StripeProvider
      publishableKey="pk_test_dfgugfjdw2uygde....">
...
</StripeProvider>
```

Cart.js

```
const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet } = useStripe();
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);


const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {

    try{
  const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/checkout`,submitedData, {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
     },
   });
  const {clientSecret,ephemeralKey,customer}=response;
  return {clientSecret,ephemeralKey,customer};
}catch(error){
    console.log(error)
}
};
 const initializePaymentSheet = async () => {
        const {
            clientSecret,ephemeralKey,customer
        } = await fetchPaymentSheetParams();
    
        const res = await initPaymentSheet({
          customerId: customer,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
          paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
          // Set `allowsDelayedPaymentMethods` to true if your business can handle payment
          //methods that complete payment after a delay, like SEPA Debit and Sofort.
          allowsDelayedPaymentMethods: true,
          customFlow: false,
          merchantDisplayName: 'Example',
          testEnv: true,
          merchantCountryCode:"US"
        });
      };

useEffect(() => {
    if(token){
    initializePaymentSheet();
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        disabled={!loading}
        title="Checkout"
        onPress={openPaymentSheet}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Your snippet looks different than what's on the example guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-collect-payment-details 

where exactly are you seeing the undefined value?

Comment: can you please provide where did you find it different? as I wrote I didn't plug the rest since initPaymentSheet is returning paymentOption undefined